# Subsetting a dataframe with the "and" condition (R)

Tags: r, subset

I define a dataframe as:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,0,4,0,4),c(3,2,0,0,2))
names(df) <- c("A","B")
```

where:

```
> df
  A B
1 1 3
2 0 2
3 4 0
4 0 0
5 4 2
```

Now I want to take only the "not completely null" rows. I've done in this way:

```
df_notNull <- subset(df,df$A!=0 & df$B!=0)
> df_notNull
      A B
    1 1 3
    5 4 2
```

Obviously I don't get what I want. The problem is not the "and" condition because I want to ignore the rows only when I have two zeros (so the "and"). Do I have to write it differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df[rowSums(df) != 0,]
#  A B
#1 1 3
#2 0 2
#3 4 0
#5 4 2
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are telling with your code is slecet when both are not 0. So, use `|` (OR) instead of `&` or use `!` in a different way.

```
df_notNull <- subset(df,df$A!=0 | df$B!=0)
```

or

```
df_notNull <- subset(df,!(df$A==0 & df$B==0))
```

as @Frank suggested, you don't need `df$`

```
df_notNull <- subset(df,A!=0 | B!=0)
df_notNull <- subset(df,!(A==0 & B==0))
```

Comment: I guess that inside `subset(df, ...)` you do not need `df$`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Reduce` with `+`

```
df[!!Reduce(`+`, df),]
#  A B
#1 1 3
#2 0 2
#3 4 0
#5 4 2
```